# Problema dataframe unique() Python

Tags: python

preciso de su ayuda;

Estoy trabajando con Jupyter python, donde básicamente estoy leyendo un archivo Excel y quiero saber los valores de columnas especificas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_os = pd.read_excel('Mi directorio', skiprows=7, usecols=['Power','Temperature','Time'])

df_os.head()
df_os.columns

df_os['MI S/N'].unique()
```

Luego en la linea `df_os['MI S/N'].unique()` me sale el siguiente error:

```
pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'MI S/N'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-c427c4cca08f> in <module>
----> 1 df_os['MI S/N'].unique() # Como se fosse o numero de serie de cada placa.

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'MI S/N'
```

A mi entender el problema estaría en los espacios de "Mi S/N" solo que no puedo modificar ese nombre.

Desde ya, agradezco si me pueden dar una ayuda en esto

Anexo:
Parte del excel que estoy analizando

```js
Details Details Details Details Details Details Details Details
MI S/N  MI S/N  11967608    11967608    11967608    11967608    11967608    11967608
MI S/N  DC Volt GridVolt    Power   Frequence   Temperature Time    Total Energy
11967608    15.4    219.38  0   60.05   24.8    01/01/2020 05:54:26 440.80
11967608    23.41   221.19  0   60.01   25  01/01/2020 05:57:41 440.80
11967608    23.11   220.91  0.05    60.03   25.09   01/01/2020 06:00:57 440.80
11967608    22.75   220.2   0.17    60.01   25.2    01/01/2020 06:04:11 440.80
11967608    22.6    220.81  0.39    59.99   25.3    01/01/2020 06:07:27 440.80
11967608    22.87   221.11  0.61    59.99   25.3    01/01/2020 06:10:42 440.80
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Link de parte de Excel: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjVaRRjGcBR6gRZH8NpU8q86npKD?e=K9ch47

Comment: podrías colocar unos datos del excel?

Comment: Ops, si. Saque una captura. Este seria una parte del excel: https://ibb.co/19G3S8c

Comment: por favor añadelo a la pregunta, y seria mejor si copias y pegas los datos :)

Comment: si haces un `print(df_os['MI S/N'])` que te sale?

Comment: SAle este error (perdon no se formatear preguntar y respuestas aun jeje) : 
KeyError: 'MI S/N'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f5b3c87a30a0> in <module>
----> 1 print(df_os['MI S/N'])

Comment: sube tu excel a la nube y pon un enlace, creo que el error es por que tienes otras columnas

Comment: @Christian Muchas gracias por responder, subiré una parte del Excel. No puedo subir todo el archivo porque son casi 9 mil líneas y no es información mía. Sigue link del Excel https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjVaRRjGcBR6gRZH8NpU8q86npKD?e=K9ch47

Comment: ya tengo mas o menos una solucion, en un momento publico la respuesta

Comment: Tienes un `KeyError`, eso básicamente te indica que no existe la columna que estas buscando, ¿y por que no existe? por que no la estás importando: `usecols=['Power','Temperature','Time']`, esto solo importa las 3 columnas mencionadas, modifica es parámetro en todo caso por `usecols=['MI S/N', 'Power','Temperature','Time']` .

Answer (score 0):

Ok el problema es el siguiente, tu tienes un Excel el cual no tiene una columnas definida desde la primera fila, pues por defecto pandas considera la primera fila de un archivo como las columnas, si hcaemos un `prind(df)` veremos esto.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Libro.xlsx')
print(df)
```

**resultado**

```py
  Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4   Unnamed: 5           Unnamed: 6    Unnamed: 7
0        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN          NaN                  NaN           NaN
1        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN          NaN                  NaN           NaN
2    Details        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN          NaN                  NaN           NaN
3     MI S/N        NaN   11967608        NaN        NaN          NaN                  NaN           NaN
4     MI S/N    DC Volt   GridVolt      Power  Frequence  Temperature                 Time  Total Energy
5   11967608       15.4     219.38          0      60.05         24.8  2020-01-01 05:54:26        440.80
6   11967608      23.41     221.19          0      60.01           25  2020-01-01 05:57:41        440.80
7   11967608      23.11     220.91       0.05      60.03        25.09  2020-01-01 06:00:57        440.80
8   11967608      22.75      220.2       0.17      60.01         25.2  2020-01-01 06:04:11        440.80
```

Aquí vemos que el nombre de las columnas es `Unnamed: 0` eso es lo que pasa al no tener definidas los nombres de la columna, otra cosa que vemos es que hay muchos valores (o campos) con el valor de `NaN` (Not a Nunber) y esto pasa por que en el archivo Excel esos campos están vacíos y como mas abajo existe valores, pandas lo rellena con `NaN`.

Entonces ¿Qué podemos hacer?, pues la respuesta es fácil, solo recortamos el *DataFrame* para poder trabajar con los valores que nos interesan y hay que renombrar las columna.

Primero tenemos que obtener el nombre de las columnas, las cuales se encuentran en la fila numero 8.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Libro.xlsx')
#print(df)

#indicamos la cuarta fila con loc y recorremos en sus valores
cols = [col for col in df.loc[4]] #compresion de lista
```

Luego tenemos que indicar cuales son los valores que nos interesan en este caso se encuentran a partir de la fila numero 5, asi que los volvemos a escoger con `iloc[]` y reemplazamos el valor del *DataFrame*

```py
df = df.iloc[5:,:] #escogemos desde la fila 5 hasta el final
print(df)
```

Ahora tenemos esto.

```
  Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5           Unnamed: 6 Unnamed: 7
5   11967608       15.4     219.38          0      60.05       24.8  2020-01-01 05:54:26     440.80
6   11967608      23.41     221.19          0      60.01         25  2020-01-01 05:57:41     440.80
7   11967608      23.11     220.91       0.05      60.03      25.09  2020-01-01 06:00:57     440.80
8   11967608      22.75      220.2       0.17      60.01       25.2  2020-01-01 06:04:11     440.80
```

Como vemos ahora ya tenemos los datos necesario, pero el nombre de las columnas sigue siendo incorrecto, asi que hay que cambiarlo. Para eso vamos a crear un nuevo *DataFrame* para poder trabajar correctamente. Existen varias formas de crear un *DataFrame* pero yo lo haré con listas, donde cada lista representara una fila, para eso tendremos que recorrer el *DataFrame* original.

```py
data = []#aqui se almacenara los datos

#recorremos en la longitud del df
for i in range(len(df)):
    row = df.iloc[i,:].tolist() #escogeos todos los datos de la fila (i)
    data.append(row)#añadimos a la lista
```

Finalmente solo nos queda crear el nuevo *DataFrame*, para eso usaremos el método de pandas para crear uno `pd.DataFrame()`, al cual le pasaremos 2 argumentos, el primero será la información que tendrá el *DataFrame* y el segundo será su atributo `columns=` para indicarle el nombre de las columnas.

```py
#cols contiene el nombre de las columnas que recorrimos al inicio (fila 4)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
print(new_df)
```

Teniendo como resultado

```
     MI S/N DC Volt GridVolt Power Frequence Temperature                Time Total Energy
0  11967608    15.4   219.38     0     60.05        24.8 2020-01-01 05:54:26       440.80
1  11967608   23.41   221.19     0     60.01          25 2020-01-01 05:57:41       440.80
2  11967608   23.11   220.91  0.05     60.03       25.09 2020-01-01 06:00:57       440.80
3  11967608   22.75    220.2  0.17     60.01        25.2 2020-01-01 06:04:11       440.80
```

Ahora si podemos hacer `df_os['MI S/N'].unique()` en nuestro caso será `new_df['MI S/N'].unique()`

```py
unicos = new_df['MI S/N'].unique()
print(unicos)
```

**resultado**

```py
[11967608]
```